# chamar método na query do laravel

Tags: php, laravel, query

Tenho essa query aqui:

```
SELECT p.descr, p.dt_hr, f.id_friend
FROM users u
JOIN friends f ON u.id = f.id_user
JOIN posts p ON p.id_user = f.id_friend
WHERE u.id = 1
```

Ela me retorna isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu to querendo girar no foreach e montar um array mais ou menos assim:

```
[0] => [
    'descr' => $ln['descr'],<br>
    'dt_hr' => $ln['dt_hr'],<br> 
    'name' => $this->getNameByIdFriend($ln['id_friend']) // pegar o nome desse usuário
]
```

ai nesse método "getNameByIdFriend", eu faria um select em outra tabela pegando o id que eu passei pra retornar o nome pra a minha posição name do meu array.

Eu faço dessa forma usando o Zend Framework 2, queria saber como posso fazer com o laravel.

Obrigado!

Comment: O nome fica em que tabela? Se for na tabela friend você pode retornar ele direto ao invés de retornar o id: SELECT p.descr, p.dt_hr, **f.nome**, se não for, você pode dar mais um join da tabela friend, para a outra que contém o nome e colocar no select

Comment: No próprio `inner join` você resolver isso, faça a junção da onde busca o nome, porque ai vai ter um desempenho ideal, já o outro em cada item selecionado fazer uma busca no banco seria um grande erro, até tem um forma com uma busca de uma só vez, mas, mesmo assim com `inner join` é a melhor forma de resolver esse problema.

Comment: O nome está na tabela users(id,nome), tabela friends(id, id_user, id_friend). Não consegui ainda não, ele ta trazendo o nome relacionado ao meu where.

Comment: Consegui resolver:

Comment: Ficou assim:
SELECT p.descr,p.dt_hr,
(SELECT u1.name FROM users u1 WHERE u1.id = f.id_friend) AS name
FROM friends f
JOIN users u ON u.id = f.id_user
JOIN posts p ON p.id_user = f.id_friend
WHERE u.id = 1
ORDER BY p.dt_hr DESC

Answer (score 0):

Usando o [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries) do Laravel, tua query deve ficar assim:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->select('posts.descr, posts.dt_hr, friends.name')
    ->join('friends', 'users.id', '=', 'friends.id_user')
    ->join('posts', 'friends.id_friend', '=', 'posts.id_user')
    ->where('users.id', 1)
    ->get();
```

Você deve receber uma [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections) contendo os resultados como objetos da classe StdClass.

(Supõe-se que a tabela `friends` tenha a coluna `name`.)